# CS50 python minimax for TicTacToe

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, cs50, minimax

In the CS50 python artificial intelligence course one of the tasks is to implement a minimax algorithm for TicTacToe. The graphical and game elements were already implemented but I am having some issues with getting the Minimax to work any help would be appreciated. The functions are:

```
"""
Tic Tac Toe Player
"""

import math

X = "X"
O = "O"
EMPTY = None


def initial_state():
    return [[EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY]] 


def player(board):
    if sum([i.count(EMPTY) for i in board]) % 2 == 1:
        return X
    else:
        return O


def actions(board):
    acts = []
    for row in range(0, 3):
        for column in range(0, 3):
            # print(row, column)
            if board[row][column] == EMPTY:
                acts.append((row, column))
    return acts


def result(board, action):
    copy = board
    try:
        if copy[action[0]][action[1]] == EMPTY:
            copy[action[0]][action[1]] = player(copy)
            return copy
        else:
            raise IndexError
    except IndexError:
        print("Invalid move")


def winner(board):
    for combos in winning_combinations(len(board)):
        if all(board[r][c] == X for r, c in combos):
            return X
        if all(board[r][c] == O for r, c in combos):
            return O

    return None


def winning_combinations(n):
    for r in range(n):
        yield [(r, c) for c in range(n)]
    for c in range(n):
        yield [(r, c) for r in range(n)]
    yield [(i, i) for i in range(n)]
    yield[(i, n-1-i) for i in range(n)]


def terminal(board):
    if sum([row.count(EMPTY) for row in board]) == 0:
        return True
    if winner(board) is not None:
        return True
    return False


def utility(board):
    if winner(board) == X:
        return 1 + sum(row.count(EMPTY) for row in board)   # so that the AI values a quick win higher
    elif winner(board) == O:
        return -1 - sum(row.count(EMPTY) for row in board)
    else:
        return 0


def minimax(board):
    best_move = None
    if player(board) == X:
        best_value = -math.inf
        for action in actions(board):
            k = MAX_value(board)
            if k > best_value:
                best_value = k
                best_move = action

    elif player(board) == O:
        best_value = math.inf
        for action in actions(board):
            k = MIN_value(board)
            if k < best_value:
                best_value = k
                best_move = action
    return best_move


def MIN_value(state):
    if terminal(state):
        return utility(state)
    value = math.inf
    for action in actions(state):
        copy = state[:]
        value = min(value, MAX_value(result(copy, action)))
    return value


def MAX_value(state):
    if terminal(state):
        return utility(state)
    value = - math.inf
    for action in actions(state):
        copy = state[:]
        value = max(value, MIN_value(result(copy, action)))
    return value
```

As far as I tell most of my functions produce the correct outputs when given a predefined input. But when I run the program as a whole it comes up with the TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable. I am aware what this error means but I cannot see where it has come from.

Comment: When you run the program, it should tell you on which line exactly is it showing up.  That can help you track down why it's happening. If you still cannot figure it out, I'd suggest trying to run it under a debugger. I personally like the one built into PyCharm, but there's other ones out there. If that's not something you're comfortable with, and don't want to learn yet, you can try old-school debugging - put some print statements around the problematic line, and see what differes from your expectation.

Comment: I have run it through the pycharm debugger (though I am not very familiar with it) and the most recent call was to: if sum([row.count(EMPTY) for row in board]) == 0. However I can't tell why this would throw an error?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't guess. If you provide a way to invoke the program, I could try debugging it for you,

Comment: I've spent some time debugging today and it appears the issue was caused within the result function. I'm not sure why but when updating the copy I made of the board it would update the original board as well? i.e copy[action[0]][action[1]] = player(copy) was updating not only the copy list but the board list as well; which was then being returned to either the MAX or MIN functions. Don't understand why it would ever do this but have fixed the issue using the copy.deepcopy() function. Could anyone explain why this was happening. thanks?

Comment: Your state is a list of lists, and the way you chose to make a copy only makes a new list containing the same orignal lists. That's what deep copy is for - it makes copies of all the nested lists as well.